# Generate a list of all theme keywords in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arccatalog

Is it possible to generate a list of all themes keywords in ArcCatalog v9.3.1? similarly, I would like to do the same for place keywords as well?

My office only have about 10 standalone ArcMap licenses, without any databases or fancy servers, other than a NAS server.

Comment: Pls clarify, A theme is associated with ArcIMs Metadata service. You can have theme keywords in metadata. Do you have current meatadata for all shapd files? I notice you have 9.3, r10 has a very powerful search that would do exaclty what you need.

Comment: I am in the process of creating metadata for my shpfiles, and i want to have a listing (in excel spreadsheet) that contains all the keywords (themes and/or place). i am now keying onto a xls one keyword at a time while i create keywords onto a shpfile in ArcCatalog. Hence, i am wondering if a function in ArcCatalog (or any software) that can generate all theme/place keywords that i put into my shpfiles. many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Metadata created is a seperate file residing along with the shape file (in your case).

I did see a few items in the [**arcscripts**](http://arcscripts.esri.com/) section (use "metadata" in the search and dig down a few pages). Most of the tools that looked like they answered your question directly are for AV3.2. However there might be a couple that you could use.

There is a free geoportal server which I think does gather all that data into one place and allows for publishing the metatdata.

I have been wanting to install and get something going with this but time has me restricted. Check it out and see if it will help. The second link is to some add-ons that you would probably want.
HTH

[Geoportal](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geoportal/index.html)

[Add-ons](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geoportal/free-addons.html)